# error/warning *** MULE MSG QUEUE IS FULL: buffer size 212992 bytes (you can tune it with --mule-msg-size) ***

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I am using `@mulefunc` decorator of uwsgi to process data in background of flask rest api call. Everything seems to be working fine though getting following message in log:

```
MULE MSG QUEUE IS FULL: buffer size 212992 bytes (you can tune it with --mule-msg-size)
```

number of hits to this function is very high. as suggested to tune `--mule-msg-size`. where can I tune it?

sample code:

```
from uwsgidecorators import mulefunc

@mulefunc
def mule(num):
    for i in range(num):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)

@app.route("/mule")
def add_mule():
    num = request.args.get("n", None)
    if num:
        mule(int(num))
    return "Mule"
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you start your uwsgi?

You could pass `--mule-msg-size` in command line.

Or you could put it in your `ini` file, and run uwsgi with `--ini=<ini file>`

```
mule-msg-size = 999999
```